# Prove that the characteristic function of a random variable is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

The definition of the characteristic function of a random variable $X$ is
$$\varphi(\lambda)=E[e^{i\lambda X}]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda x}\,dP(x),$$
where $dP$ is the distribution of the random variable.

> Prove that the characteristic function of a random variable is uniformly continuous.

My attempt of the proof is:

$$|\varphi(\lambda) -\varphi(\lambda') | = |\int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{i\lambda x} -e^{i\lambda' x} ) dP(x)|  $$

$$\leq    |\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda' x} (e^{i(\lambda - \lambda') x}-1)  dP(x)|  $$

$$\leq  \int_{-\infty}^\infty   |e^{i\lambda' x}|   |e^{i(\lambda - \lambda') x}-1|    dP(x)      $$

Then use the fact that the absolute value of a complex exponential is 1.
$$=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty      |e^{i(\lambda - \lambda') x}-1|    dP(x)      $$

Then use the inequality that the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372337/inequality-involving-complex-exponential) $|e^{ihx}-1|\le |hx|$.

$$\leq  \int_{-\infty}^\infty      |(\lambda - \lambda') x|    dP(x)      $$

I don't know how to do next. The textbook said I need to use Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. I don't know how to use that. I think I am stuck that how to prove one function is uniformly continuous. I only know this definition of uniformly continuous:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon \quad  \text{whenever} \quad |x-y| < \delta
$$
and $\delta$ is independent of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Terminology is not always as standard as one thinks it might be. In this case, I have no idea what you mean by the *characteristic function*, so a good start to your post would be if you first said exactly what that function is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've proved that
$$|\varphi(\lambda)-\varphi(\lambda')|\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty|e^{i(\lambda-\lambda')x}-1|dP(x).$$
Let $\phi(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|e^{i\lambda x}-1|dP(x)$, then $|\varphi(\lambda)-\varphi(\lambda')|\leq\phi(\lambda-\lambda')$.

We prove that $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\phi(\lambda)=0=\phi(0)$. Recalling the definition of $\phi$, since $|e^{i\lambda x}-1|\leq 2$ and $\lim_{\lambda\to0}|e^{i\lambda x}-1|=0$ for all $x$, and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2dP(x)=2<\infty$, the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem tells that
$$\lim_{\lambda\to0}\phi(\lambda)=\lim_{\lambda\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|e^{i\lambda x}-1|dP(x)=0.$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that $0\leq\phi(\lambda)<\epsilon$ for all $|\lambda|<\delta$; therefore, whenever $|\lambda-\lambda'|<\delta$, we have
$$|\varphi(\lambda)-\varphi(\lambda')|\leq\phi(\lambda-\lambda')<\epsilon.$$
This proves the uniform continuity of $\varphi$.

*Remark.* You've got a further step that $|\varphi(\lambda)-\varphi(\lambda')|\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty|(\lambda-\lambda')x|dP(x)$, which implies that $\varphi$ is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) and then uniformly continuous **as long as** $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|dP(x)<\infty$. But this is not always true. For example, the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), [whose characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Characteristic_function) is uniformly continuous, although [the first moment does not exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments).

**About the DCT things.** Let $\{\lambda_n\}$ be an arbitrary sequence that tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Since $|e^{i\lambda_n x}-1|\leq 2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|e^{i\lambda_n x}-1|=0$, [the standard DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) implies that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(\lambda_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty|e^{i\lambda_n x}-1|dP(x)=0.$$
Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi(\lambda_n)=0$ for all equences $\{\lambda_n\}$ that tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, which implies that $\lim_{\lambda\to0}\phi(\lambda)=0$ by [Heine's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences). This is the so called *Dominated Convergence Theorem with "continuous" limits*, and has been discussed many times in this site, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412510/using-dominated-convergence-theorem-with-continuous-limits?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681712/extending-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-to-continuous-limits?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more information.

Comment: In my version of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu$. The conditions are $|f_n|$ are bounded and $f_n \to f$ where f is measurable. But here the limit is going to zero ($\lambda \to 0$), not the infinity. So I am confused. Do you have any tutorial link? Or if you want me to open a new question to answer?

Comment: @Jackie You can use your version of the DCT to prove that $\phi(\lambda_n)\to0$ for all sequences $\{\lambda_n\}$ with $\lambda_n\to0$. This will imply that $\phi(\lambda)\to0$ as $\lambda\to0$ by the [Heine theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3332261/heine-theorem-intuition-relationship-between-limit-of-a-sequence-and-limit-of-a). I remember that someone asked about this several months ago in this site, but I failed to find the exact post.

Comment: Can you tell me what the version of DCT you are using?

Comment: @Jackie OK. Let me add some more lines in the answer.